# Watermark repeatation in subreports

Tags: crystal-reports

Lets Say, I have 10 subreports in a report.I put each subreports in detail section of crystal report(e.g: details a,details b, details c in this way) I want to repeat a watermark in each subreport page without putting the watermark in each subreport separately. How may I achieve that? Any feedback will be highly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Please post your comment as answer. Summarize the steps and then mark your answer as correct answer. Its okay to answer your own question if you found a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the instructions in this link and it works perfectly.
http://www.microassist.com/software-tips/crystal-reports-add-a-watermark-to-your-report/